# Is there something more informative than :set showimplicits for deciphering unification failures?

Tags: idris

Is there something more informative than :set showimplicits for tracking down unification errors? I'm currently getting this and have no idea where to go from here:[image: A confusing unification error screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is "No, not really", unfortunately. However, I don't like seeing bad error messages so if you can provide more details maybe it's something we can look into and improve.

The longer answer is that there is a problem with the way Idris reports errors here, and I expect what's happening is similar to this: https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/issues/2126

I notice you only show the second "specifically" part of the unification error. It's likely the real problem is in the first part. Since unification failures might be temporary and might be solved when the elaborator gets more information, the error message gets updated when that extra information turns up (usually from some other part of the term). What's happened here is that the part which failed on the first attempt is now okay, but some other part is still broken.

For now, I'd suggest ignoring the "specifically" bit and looking at the first part (which I suppose might be quite big). Otherwise, if the relevant part of your program is easily explainable perhaps someone on the mailing list can help.

I'll get to fixing the relevant issue eventually though...